# Given graph $G=(V,E)$, explain what it means if $uv\notin E$, but containing cycle with edge $uv$

Tags: graph-theory

An exercise question asks me to find the vertices $uv$ given graph graph $G = (V,E)$ such that

1. $uv\notin E$, and
2. $G + uv$ contains a cycle with edge $uv$.

I am having some trouble understanding these properties. How can $uv$ not be connected by an edge, yet the graph $G$ can contain a cycle **with** the edge $uv$?

Comment: Item ii) means that if you add an edge from $u$ to $v$, then you get a cycle including that edge. "$G+uv$" presumably means the graph $G$ with the one added edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it forms a cycle **once** you add $uv$. This is true precisely when there is a path between $v$ and $u$ in $G$.

To form the cycle, go from $v$ to $u$, add in the edge, follow it and end up back where you started at $v$.

Comment: Thanks! OK, this makes sense :)